# Creating messaging (chatting) functions in Django

Tags: django, chat, messaging

I created models for messaging between users of my project. My messaging models:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(_('id'), primary_key=True, default=hex_uuid, editable=False, 
                         max_length=32)
    chat_participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'chat'
        verbose_name_plural = 'chats'


class Message(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(_('id'), primary_key=True, default=hex_uuid, editable=False, 
                         max_length=32)
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(_('text'), max_length=1500, null=True, blank=True)
    send_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'message'
        verbose_name_plural = 'messages'


class MessageRecipient(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(_('id'), primary_key=True, default=hex_uuid, editable=False, 
                         max_length=32)
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_seen = models.BooleanField(_('is_seen'), default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'message_recipient'
        verbose_name_plural = 'message recipients'
        unique_together = ('message', 'recipient')
```

1. How can I  automatically assign 'author' field in Message class (model) to the ID of user who writes a message? Now I need by myself choose the 'author' from the (not real) users that are in my database, but it is wrong, it has to be automatically selected depending on who writes the message. Or, let's, say who's account this message is being written from.
2. In MessageRecipient class (model) I have to choose recipient myself, and I can choose not only among the participants of the particular chat group where the message has to be arrived, but also from all other users from my database, who even not in that particular chat. How can I limit the range of recipients so that I can choose ONLY those people who are in the chat where the particular message (look at message field) arrives?

Comment: You normally assign the user in the *view* where you create the message.

Comment: as @WillemVanOnsem noted, the corresponding views and forms for these models look to be more of concern here. Post the code for those and we can better understand your needs!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create a model called `Message` then add `sender` and `receiver` fields to it like this:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_lenght=500)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Then in your **view** you will get all the messages and handle the **form** validation(the **form** will have 1 field called `text` and thats it):

```
def messages(request, pk):
    sender = request.user
    receiver = User.objects.get( # query the user for a receiver )
    sent_messages = Message.objects.filter(sender=sender, receiver=receiver)
    received_messages = Message.objects.filter(sender=receiver, receiver=sender)
    messages = sent_messages.union(received_messages)
    if request.method == 'POST'
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = form.save(commit=False)
            message.sender = request.user
            message.receiver = User.objects.get( # query the user for a receiver )
            message.save()
            return redirect('messages', pk=receiver.pk)
    else:
        form = MessageForm()
    return render(redirect, 'messages_template.html', {'receiver': receiver,
                                                       'messages': messages,
                                                       'form': form})
```

And then in the template:

**messages_template.html**

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {{ message.sender}} says: {{ message.text }}
{% endfor %}

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" value="Send"></button>
<form>
```